# How to connect 64-bit R (without setting it to 32-bit) to 32- bit MS Access

Tags: r, ms-access, rodbc

I am wondering if it is possible to connect 64-bit R to  Ms Access and upload a file to the database .I cannot change R to 32- bit.

I tried this

```
odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=S:/folder/Database.mdb")
```

and this

```
db <- "S:/folder/Database.mdb"
con2 <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db)
sqlSave(con2, joint_df)
```

However I always get this error message

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=S:/folder/Database.mdb") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: Status IM002, Code 0, Message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=S:/folder/Database.mdb") :
  ODBC-Connection failed
```

Comment: In short: you can't. You either need to use a 64-bit database driver, or 32-bit R, and while there have been people installing the 64-bit database engine alongside 32-bit Access, that's not supported and can lead to buggy behavior

Comment: @ErikA thanks that is the answer I have been looking for